# How to evaluate $\int\frac{ \sin^8 x - \cos^8x } { 1 - 2\sin^2 x \cdot \cos^2 x }\mathrm{d}x$?

Tags: integration, trigonometry, trigonometric-integrals

I would like to calculate the following integral:
$$
   \int\frac{ \sin^8 x - \cos^8x }
        { 1 - 2\sin^2 x \cdot \cos^2 x }\mathrm{d}x.
$$

---

I have tried to rewrite the integral as:

$$
   \int\frac{(  \sin^4 x  +  \cos^4x)  \cdot   (  \sin^2 x  +  \cos^2 x)  \cdot  ( \sin^2 x  -  \cos^2 x )}
     {  1  -  2\sin^2x \cdot  \cos^2 x  }\mathrm{d}x 
$$

but I don't know how to go on.

Comment: Hint: $1 = (\sin^2(x)+ \cos^2(x))^2 = \cdots$

Comment: Was [this same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2895190/integrate-the-given-expression) not asked and answered yesterday?

Comment: We can use substitution for $\tan(x)$

Comment: You can use that $sinx^2+cosx^2=1$. Expand the rest and use thatv$sinx^2=1-cosx^2$ and $cosx^2=1-sinx^2$

Comment: You should clarify what kind of answer you are looking for compared to the one already posted on this same question you asked last day. You could have done this by editing that post itself instead of asking it again. This looks like an exact duplicate of your previous post.

Comment: @Sobi yes you are right

Comment: @StubbornAtom i will edit my question accordingly . I am new to the site . So sorry . And thanks for the advice

Comment: @Fareed AF not able to understand what you are trying to say :(

Comment: What do you mean by "I do not want to use (this)..."? That is the most direct, obvious method to simplify the integrand to $-\cos 2x$.

Comment: @Deepak I was looking for some other method to answer the question . i thought that this site has really intelligent people , So I asked about some other method .

Comment: I'm sure it's possible to come up with a more indirect and difficult method but in my experience "really intelligent people" tend to favour the neat, the direct and the elegant. Anyway, other methods will also use one or more trig identities for the simplification so they're not that different in spirit.

Comment: though "intelligent people " tend to favour simpler method . But THEY KNOW OTHER METHODS ALSO . Also the simpler methods are "taught at school and colleges" also . Here people come to learn something new . also simpler method are not easy to think of .

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Your Integrand is equal to $$1-2\cos^2(x)$$
For the proof, Show that

$$(1-2\cos^2(x))(1-2\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x))-(\sin(x)^8-\cos(x)^8)=0$$
It is
$$\sin^8(x)-\cos^8(x)=(\sin^2(x)-cos^2(x))(\sin^4(x)+cos^4(x))=$$
$$-\cos(2x)(\sin^4(x)+\cos^4(x))$$
and from

$$\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$$ we get by squaring

$$\sin^4(x)+\cos^4(x)=1-2\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)$$

Comment: I.e. $-\cos 2x$?

Comment: $$-\cos(2x)=-(2\cos^2(x)-1)$$, yes it is.

Comment: But how did this come ??

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner could you please tell how to prove (1−2cos2(x))(1−2sin2(x)cos2(x))−(sin(x)8−cos(x)8)=0

Comment: Very neat trick, Dr. Graubner!

Answer (score 1):

Given $$\int \dfrac{\sin^8x-\cos^8x}{1-2\sin^2x\cos^2x}dx$$Now multiply numerator and denominator by $\dfrac{4\sec^4x}{\cos4x+3}$ and we get$$\int\dfrac{(\tan^2x-1)\sec^2x}{(1+\tan^2x)^2}$$
And now use substitution $u=\tan x$ and $du=\sec^2xdx$and if you find $$\int\dfrac{u^2-1}{(u^2+1)^2}du$$ you will get the answer

Comment: How did you think of second step that is Now multiply numerator and denominator by 4sec4xcos4x+3 ?? And also how did you get the expression in third step ?

Comment: @WilliamWills For such type of integrals, it would be easy to bring it in the form of $\tan$ and then use substitution. So, eventually I did.

Comment: @user587574 but how did you convert integrand into tan x . how did you think of multiplying by 4sec4x\(cos4x+3) ??

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:
$$\sin^4x+\cos^4x=(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)^2-2\sin^2x\cos^2x=1-2\sin^2x\cos^2x.$$